# IOS: Facebook integration - Sharing current url of UIwebview

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, twitter, uiwebview

So i'm in the process of making a news reader app. Its source is a RSS feed, the user can click the stories that are presented in a tableview. This then opens the stories in a web view. I have a share feature setup for Facebook and Twitter, however I need this to automatically add the current url of the webview to the users post. Any help for a novice would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code in my .m

```
- (IBAction)social:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *share = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass on the news!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Post to Twitter", @"Post to Facebook", nil];

    //You must show the action sheet for the user to see it.
    [share showInView:self.view];
}

(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //Each button title we gave to our action sheet is given a tag starting with 0.
    if (actionSheet.tag == 0) {

    //Check Twitter accessibility and at least one account is setup.
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this article I found using the 'Pass'  iPhone app: "];

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least one Twitter account setup and your device is using iOS6 or above!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

} else if (actionSheet.tag == 1) {

    //Check Facebook accessibility and at least one account is setup.
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *facebookSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
        [facebookSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this article I found using the 'Pass'  iPhone app:"];

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [self presentViewController:facebookSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't post a Facebook post right now, make sure you have at least one Facebook account setup and your device is using iOS6 or above!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To estract the url name you have to use:

```
NSString *urlWeb = webViewName.request.URL.absoluteString
```

If you want to share the page title too you can use javascript like that:

```
NSString *webTitle = [webViewName stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```